# Tensorflow YOLO Object Detection Loss Exploding

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, yolo

I am trying to implement and train YOLO on my own, based on this implementation https://github.com/allanzelener/YAD2K/.  The problems I am having is the width/height values in my prediction tensor are exploding and I never see an IOU above 0 between my prediction objects and ground truth objects.  This all goes wrong within the first few minibatches of the first epoch.  The loss and most of my prediction width/heights are `nan`.

My image size is `416x416`, I'm using 5 anchors, and have 5 classes.  I'm dividing the image into a `13x13` grid for a prediction tensor of `[batch_size, 13, 13, 5, 10]`. The ground truths for each batch are `[batch_size, 13, 13, 5, 5]`, without one hot for the class probabilities.

Below is my loss function (based on https://github.com/allanzelener/YAD2K/blob/master/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py#L152), which passes the image to my model and then calls `predict_transform` which reshapes the tensor and transforms the coordinates.

```
def loss_custom(true_box_grid, x):
    # training=training is needed only if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    y_ = model(x, training=training)
    # (batch, rows, cols, anchors, vals)
    center_coords, wh_coords, obj_scores, class_probs = DetectNet.predict_transform(y_)
    detector_mask = create_mask(true_box_grid)
    total_loss = 0    

    pred_wh_half = wh_coords / 2.
    # bottom left corner
    pred_mins = center_coords - pred_wh_half
    # top right corner
    pred_maxes = center_coords + pred_wh_half

    true_xy = true_box_grid[..., 0:2]
    true_wh = true_box_grid[..., 2:4]
    true_wh_half = true_wh / 2.
    true_mins = true_xy - true_wh_half
    true_maxes = true_xy + true_wh_half

    # max bottom left corner
    intersect_mins = tf.math.maximum(pred_mins, true_mins)
    # min top right corner
    intersect_maxes = tf.math.minimum(pred_maxes, true_maxes)    
    intersect_wh = tf.math.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
    # product of difference between x max and x min, y max and y min
    intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]


    pred_areas = wh_coords[..., 0] * wh_coords[..., 1]
    true_areas = true_wh[..., 0] * true_wh[..., 1]

    union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas
    iou_scores = intersect_areas / union_areas

    # Best IOUs for each location.
    iou_scores = tf.expand_dims(iou_scores, 4)
    best_ious = tf.keras.backend.max(iou_scores, axis=4)  # Best IOU scores.
    best_ious = tf.expand_dims(best_ious, 4)

    # A detector has found an object if IOU > thresh for some true box.
    object_detections = tf.keras.backend.cast(best_ious > 0.6, dtype=tf.float32)

    no_obj_weights = params.noobj_loss_weight * (1 - object_detections) * (1 - detector_mask[...,:1])
    no_obj_loss = no_obj_weights * tf.math.square(obj_scores)

    # could use weight here on obj loss
    obj_conf_loss = params.obj_loss_weight * detector_mask[...,:1] * tf.math.square(1 - obj_scores)
    conf_loss = no_obj_loss + obj_conf_loss

    matching_classes = tf.cast(true_box_grid[...,4], tf.int32)
    matching_classes = tf.one_hot(matching_classes, params.num_classes)
    class_loss = detector_mask[..., :1] * tf.math.square(matching_classes - class_probs)

    # keras_yolo does a sigmoid on center_coords here but they should already be between 0 and 1 from predict_transform
    pred_boxes = tf.concat([center_coords, wh_coords], axis=-1)

    matching_boxes = true_box_grid[..., :4]
    coord_loss = params.coord_loss_weight * detector_mask[..., :1] * tf.math.square(matching_boxes - pred_boxes)

    confidence_loss_sum = tf.keras.backend.sum(conf_loss)
    classification_loss_sum = tf.keras.backend.sum(class_loss)
    coordinates_loss_sum = tf.keras.backend.sum(coord_loss)

    # not sure why .5 is here, maybe to make sure numbers don't get too large
    total_loss = 0.5 * (confidence_loss_sum + classification_loss_sum + coordinates_loss_sum)            

    return total_loss
```

Below is `predict_transform` (based on https://github.com/allanzelener/YAD2K/blob/master/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py#L66) which reshapes the prediction tensor into a grid in order to compare with the ground truth objects.  For the center coordinates, object scores, and class probabilities it does a sigmoid or softmax.

For the width height coordinates it performs the exponential operation on them (to make them positive) and multiplies them by the anchors. This seems to be where they start exploding.

```
def predict_transform(predictions):
        predictions = tf.reshape(predictions, [-1, params.grid_height, params.grid_width, params.num_anchors, params.pred_vec_len])

        conv_dims = predictions.shape[1:3]
        conv_height_index = tf.keras.backend.arange(0, stop=conv_dims[0])
        conv_width_index = tf.keras.backend.arange(0, stop=conv_dims[1])
        conv_height_index = tf.tile(conv_height_index, [conv_dims[1]]) # (169,) tensor with 0-12 repeating
        conv_width_index = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(conv_width_index, 0), [conv_dims[0], 1]) # (13, 13) tensor with x offset in each row
        conv_width_index = tf.keras.backend.flatten(tf.transpose(conv_width_index)) # (169,) tensor with 13 0's followed by 13 1's, etc (y offsets)
        conv_index = tf.transpose(tf.stack([conv_height_index, conv_width_index])) # (169, 2)
        conv_index = tf.reshape(conv_index, [1, conv_dims[0], conv_dims[1], 1, 2]) # y offset, x offset
        conv_dims = tf.cast(tf.reshape(conv_dims, [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]), tf.float32) # grid_height x grid_width, max dims of anchors

        # makes the center coordinate between 0 and 1, each grid cell is normalized to 1 x 1
        center_coords = tf.math.sigmoid(predictions[...,:2])
        conv_index = tf.cast(conv_index, tf.float32)
        center_coords = (center_coords + conv_index) / conv_dims

        # makes the objectness score a probability between 0 and 1
        obj_scores = tf.math.sigmoid(predictions[...,4:5])

        anchors = DetectNet.get_anchors()
        anchors = tf.reshape(anchors, [1, 1, 1, params.num_anchors, 2])
        # exp to make width and height positive then multiply by anchor dims to resize box to anchor
        # should fit close to anchor, normalizing by conv_dims should make it between 0 and approx 1
        wh_coords = (tf.math.exp(predictions[...,2:4])*anchors) / conv_dims

        # apply sigmoid to class scores to make them probabilities
        class_probs = tf.keras.activations.softmax(predictions[..., 5 : 5 + params.num_classes])

        # (batch, rows, cols, anchors, vals)
        return center_coords, wh_coords, obj_scores, class_probs
```

I have another doubt in creating the ground truth data, based on https://github.com/allanzelener/YAD2K/blob/master/yad2k/models/keras_yolo.py#L352.  In the below `box[0]` and `box[1]` are the center coordinates, `i` and `j` are the grid cell coordinates (between 0 and 13), and `box[2]` and `box[3]` are the width and height.

They have all been normalized to be within the grid coordinates (0 to 13). Its placing the object in the ground truth grid with its corresponding best anchor.  `box[0] - j` and `box[1] - i` ensure the center coordinates are between 0 and 1.

However I don't understand `np.log(box[2] / anchors[best_anchor][0])`, as the anchors are also on the grid coordinate scale, and the quotient may be less than 1, which will produce a negative number after the `log`.  I often see negative widths and heights in my ground truth data as I am training, and don't know what to make of that.

```
if best_iou > 0:
            adjusted_box = np.array(
                [
                    box[0] - j, # center should be between 0 and 1, like prediction will be
                    box[1] - i,
                    np.log(box[2] / anchors[best_anchor][0]), # quotient might be less than one, not sure why log is used
                    np.log(box[3] / anchors[best_anchor][1]),
                    box[4] # class label
                ],
                dtype=np.float32
            )
            true_box_grid[i, j, best_anchor] = adjusted_box
```

Also here is my model, which is very watered down because of my lack of computational resources.

```
def create_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(6, 3, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(8, 3, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())

    model.add(Conv2D(12, 3, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(Conv2D(8, 1, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(Conv2D(12, 3, padding='same', data_format='channels_last', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(params.grid_height * params.grid_width * params.pred_vec_len * params.num_anchors, activation='relu'))

    return model
```

I'm wondering what I can do to prevent the predicted widths and heights, and thus the loss from exploding.  The exponential is there to ensure they are positive, which makes sense.  I could also do a sigmoid on them, but I don't want to restrict them to be between 0 and 1. In the YOLO paper, they mention that they pretrain their network so that the layer weights are already initialized when the YOLO training begins.  Is this a problem of initializing the network properly?

Comment: How big is your dataset? Do you think that the size of your model is justified for the size and complexity of the model? Did you try tuning the hyperparameters by using a Grid-search algorithm? Why not try training it on Colab without a "watered down" model version? Please give more fundamental information in the future.... like which dataset, size of dataset, etc. providing the shape of one element of the dataset will not help,,,,,

Comment: I'm using the Waymo open dataset, its about 15000 images.  Its a tfrecord file of about 6 GB.  I'm training it on a 12 GB GPU.  I haven't tried a grid search algorithm.  I will try Colab and a grid search algorithm, thank you